# Pandas - Deleting rows with string a in column x and string b in column y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm looking for a method to delete rows that contain certain different strings in different columns at the same time.

I have a dataset like this:

```python
    A       B      C       D
0  in    summer    x      NaN
1  in    summer    y      0.0
2  out   summer    g      3.2
3  out   winter    h      4.4
4  in    winter    e      0.0
5  in    summer    y      2.6
```

I want to get rid of all entries that in A contain out, in B contain winter, and get rid of all NaN and 0.0 values in D

To get rid of the NaNs I used:

```
df.dropna(subset = ['D'])
```

and this to clean out winter from B

```
df[~df.B.str.contains('winter')] 
df[~df.A.str.contains('out')] --> the above for winter will be undone
```

But when trying to use the upper command again to get rid of out in A, the first command acts like it never happened and the winter entries are all back, except that I sorted out the out in A. And how do I get rid of the 0.0 float values in D as well?

Desired output:

```python
    A       B      C       D
5  in    summer    y      2.6
```

Sorry, I'm super inexperienced in Python but I need to do this for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code (`df[~df.…)]`) is that it creates a **temporary** output,
but the original DataFrame remains unchanged.

To get your expected result:

- run *drop* passing indices of all rows which you can select by comparison
  with any fixed values,
- then, to filter out *NaN* in *D* column, run *dropna*, as in your code,
  but this should be a **chained** statement,
- save the result back under *df*.

Example:

```
df = df.drop(df.query("A == 'out' or B == 'winter' or D == 0").index).dropna(subset = ['D'])
```

Then when you print *df* you will get:

```
    A       B  C    D
5  in  summer  y  2.6
```

## Another option

Run:

```
df = df.drop(df.query("A == 'out' or B == 'winter' or D == 0 or D != D").index)
```

This code relies on the fact that *NaN* is **not** equal to another *NaN*,
so you can do it without explicit call to *dropna*.

## Yet another option

Just *query* for the **wanted** rows and save the result back under *df*:

```
df = df.query("A != 'out' and B != 'winter' and D != 0 and D == D")
```

To see any "partial set" of rows to be dropped, you can run *query* with
the respective partial query, e.g.:

```
df.query("A == 'out'")
```

will show rows with the "unwanted" value in *A* column.

If you want to print rows with "unwanted" values in e.g. 2 columns, extend the query
accordingly:

```
df.query("A == 'out' or B == 'winter'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea I was only messing with a temporary output! I actually used your latter statement and it works like a charm and saves me a lot of typing.

Comment: do you happen to know how to print two of the "opposite" tables, like df1 is the one excluding winter and df2 is excluding summer. So far it always prints out the latter and never both of them

Answer (score 0):

Chain multiple conditions by `&` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = ~df.B.str.contains('winter')
m2 = ~df.A.str.contains('out')
m3 =  df.D.fillna(0).ne(0)

df = df[m1 & m2 & m3]

print (df)
    A       B  C    D
5  in  summer  y  2.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Love this as well, although I must say the query statement from the other contributor makes it easier for me as I need to do it for around 90 df's and it's surely getting out of hand with lines

Comment: @Allyx - It is up you you, my opinion query is slowier,so I not prefer it.

Comment: @Allyx - Also in my opinion here use `drop` is really overcomplicated.

Comment: @Allyx - Also not problem `contains` filter substrings and another answer not? Answer are completely different output, e.g. if change `winter` to `winter1` another answer failed.

Comment: So far it's only important for me to filter out winter or summer, the columns only consist of either of the 2 without any numbers or letters that were added. I am using the query statement

Comment: @Allyx - OK, I suggest not use it, but is up to you.